# What is the best way to access the user's first_name?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I am developing a canvas app (iframe) and would like to get access to the logged in user's first_name.  **What is the best way to access the user's first_name?**

I could access it via the graph api or FQL, but that seems quite slow due to the extra round-trip to Facebook's servers.

What about prepared FQL - does this still exist?  Or what about including the first_name in the signed_request, where the user_id and other information is sent?

Thanks in advance,

fbwb

Answer (score 1):

Doing a graph API call for JUST the first_name field should be nearly instant and trivial. The following example returned in 60ms for me:

```js
FB.api('me', {'fields': 'first_name'}, function(user) {
    console.log(user.first_name);
});
```

And in PHP:

```php
$user = $fb->api('me', array('fields' => 'first_name'));
print $user['first_name'];
```

Preload FQL no longer works, the other alternative is to use XFBML `<fb:name />` but that is being deprecated.

Your best bet is to just make the call from your server before you show the page. You can also cache this or store it in a session or cookie for repeat uses.

Comment: Thanks...  That's JS, right?  I am using PHP, though.  Also, is there any way to get the first_name without an extra request?  I am in Asia, and the roundtrip is not as quick as within the US.  :)

Comment: added PHP and some more thoughts